# Eclipse ADT + JDT Plugin Issue

Tags: eclipse, adt, eclipse-jdt

I am running Version: 3.7.2 Build id: I20110613-1736 from Ubuntu 12.04 and eclipse-jdt package.

After installing the ADT plugin I do not see the window > preferences > Android menu.

I have loaded eclipse with '-console' and ran 'diag com.android.ide.eclipse.adt'

osgi> diag 3
reference:file:plugins/com.android.ide.eclipse.adt_20.0.3.v201208082019-427395.jar [3]
  Direct constraints which are unresolved:
    Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt_0.0.0.
    Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui_0.0.0.
    Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.launching_0.0.0.
    Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.junit_0.0.0.
    Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.junit.runtime_0.0.0.

This seems odd because for example these both exist in the same dir:

/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.ui_3.7.2.v20120109-1427.jar
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.7.3.v20120119-1537.jar

and *core is loaded:

osgi> ss org.eclipse.jdt.core

Framework is launched.

id      State       Bundle
315     <>    org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.7.3.v20120119-1537

Anyone seen this or have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please install Eclipse by downloading it from the website, not by using the package manager. I'm aware that this contradicts all Ubuntu recommendations, but people run into all kinds of troubles with the packaged version, which tries to outsmart the Eclipse internal P2 installation mechanism by not allowing the installation of *required features*.

ADT requires [Eclipse WST](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/ws/) to be installed, so please make sure this is available in your installation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. The thing is this has only happened sinece updating from helios, so there must be an issue here, and considering it picks up the other plugin bundles in the same dir is slightly confusing! I also have web tools installed already.